# Mongodb - Get record that match exactly an array but regardless of the order of elements in the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a column like

```
A.  'col' : [
            '5ed3ede8844f0f351100000c',
            '5ed3f117a844e0471100000d'
    ]
```

or some other case data

```
B.   'col' : [
            '5ed3ede8844f0f351100000c'
     ]

C.   'col' : [
            '5ed3ede8844f0f351100000c',
            '5ed3f117a844e0471100000d',
            '5ed3f18132f50c491100000e'
     ]
```

How to get `A` record that match exactly an array but regardless of the order of elements in the array with one query

Example

`.find({'col': ['5ed3ede8844f0f351100000c','5ed3f117a844e0471100000d']})`

or `.find({'col': ['5ed3f117a844e0471100000d', '5ed3ede8844f0f351100000c']})`

How to do that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find a record that match exactly a specified array without taking into consideration the order of the elements within the array, you can combine the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) and the [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) query operators.

So for example:

```
.find({ 'col': { "$size": 2, "$all": ['5ed3f117a844e0471100000d', '5ed3ede8844f0f351100000c'] } })
```

Note: you can also use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) query operator, but for your case it looks like the $all is a better fit